# Pandas - Updating columns based on several conditions - group by method

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I am aiming to the below output.

| A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0000 | ZZZ | 987 | QW1 | 8 | first three-four col and offset |
| 0000 | ZZZ | 987 | QW1 | -8 | first three-four col and offset |
| 0000 | ZZZ | 987 | QW1 | -8 | first or no match |
| 1111 | AAA | 123 | AB1 | 1 | first three-four col and offset |
| 1111 | AAA | 123 | CD1 | -1 | first three-four col and offset |
| 2222 | BBB | 456 | EF1 | -4 | first three-four col and offset |
| 2222 | BBB | 456 | GH1 | -1 | first three-four col and offset |
| 2222 | BBB | 456 | IL1 | 5 | first three-four col and offset |
| 3333 | CCC | 789 | MN1 | 2 | first two col and offset |
| 3333 | CCC | 101 | MN1 | -2 | first two col and offset |
| 4444 | DDD | 121 | UYT | 6 | first two col and offset |
| 4444 | DDD | 131 | FB1 | -5 | first two col and offset |
| 4444 | DDD | 141 | UYT | -1 | first two col and offset |
| 5555 | EEE | 151 | CB1 | 3 | first two col and offset |
| 5555 | EEE | 161 | CR1 | -3 | first two col and offset |
| 5555 | EEE | 161 | CR1 | -5 | first or no match |
| 6666 | FFF | 111 | CB1 | 4 | first or no match |
| 7777 | GGG | 222 | ZB1 | 10.5 | first three-four col and small offset |
| 7777 | GGG | 222 | ZB1 | -10 | first three-four col and small offset |

1st rule) the first three columns must equal each other - regardless of the fourth, which can either be equal or not. Each combination must have the associated numbers (col E) offset to zero (can be from 2 to X records combined). IT SHOULD WORK EVEN WITH UNEVEN ENTRIES.

2nd rule) the first two columns must equal each other - regardless of the fourth, which can either be equal or not. Each combination must have the associated numbers (col E) offset to zero (can be from 2 to X records combined). IT SHOULD WORK EVEN WITH UNEVEN ENTRIES.

3rd rule) no match.

4th rule) the first three columns must equal each other - regardless of the fourth, which can either be equal or not. Each combination can have a difference of `0.5` AT MOST (col E) and NO offset to zero (can be from 2 to X records combined). IT SHOULD WORK EVEN WITH UNEVEN ENTRIES.

Please see my code below.

Through the below code, I am able to get a similar result, however, this way does not work with uneven entries, for instance the first three rows would result as following:

| A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0000 | ZZZ | 987 | QW1 | 8 | first or no match |
| 0000 | ZZZ | 987 | QW1 | -8 | first or no match |
| 0000 | ZZZ | 987 | QW1 | -8 | first or no match |

Instead of the following:

| A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0000 | ZZZ | 987 | QW1 | 8 | first three-four col and offset |
| 0000 | ZZZ | 987 | QW1 | -8 | first three-four col and offset |
| 0000 | ZZZ | 987 | QW1 | -8 | first or no match |

Code so far:

```
m1 = df.groupby(['A', 'B', 'C'])['E'].transform('sum').eq(0)  # Rule 1
m2 = df.groupby(['A', 'B'])['E'].transform('sum').eq(0)  # Rule 2
m3 = df.groupby(['A', 'B', 'C'])['E'].transform('sum').abs().le(0.5)  # Rule 4

df['new'] = np.select([m1, m2, m3], ['first three-four col and offset',
                      'first two col and offset', 'first three-four col and small offset'], 'first or no match')
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### 1. Define a function `_thresh_sum`

We can define a recursive function which takes the input argument as a 1D numpy array and returns the 1D boolean array having the same shape as the input array

```py
from numba import jit

@jit(nopython=True)
def _thresh_sum(arr, indices, flags, offset, thresh):
    if flags[indices].any(): return

    s = np.abs(arr[indices].sum())
    if s <= thresh and len(indices) > 1:
        flags[indices] = True
        return

    for i, _ in enumerate(arr[offset:]):
        new_offset = offset + i + 1
        new_indices = np.array(list(indices) + [offset + i])
        _thresh_sum(arr, new_indices, flags, new_offset, thresh)


def thresh_sum(arr, thresh=0):
    flags = np.full(len(arr), False)
    _thresh_sum(np.array(arr), 
                np.array([], dtype='int'), flags, 0, thresh + 1e-6)
    return flags
```

**Intuition behind `_thresh_sum`**

- Essentially we are performing a depth-first search on the input array to check for all the possible paths where the vertices in a given path are the elements from the array
- If for a given path the sum of all the numbers in the path is less than or equal to the given **threshold**, then we stop further searching on the current path and explore other paths with different starting node
- If a path found then we flag all the numbers/vertices in a path

We can further improve the **performance** of code by compiling the function `_thresh_sum` directly to **machine code** with the help of technique called **just in time compilation** using `numba`

**Note**: It is [`NP-Hard`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) type problem. As the number of elements per unique group increases the computational complexity of the problem will increase in the order of approximately `O(2^n)`.

#### 2. `Group` and `transform` with `thresh_sum`

Now we group the dataframe as per the given rules `1`, `2`, `4` and `transform` column `E` using the function `thresh_sum` corresponding to each rule

```
m1 = df.groupby(['A', 'B', 'C'])['E'].transform(thresh_sum) # Rule 1
m2 = df[~m1].groupby(['A', 'B'])['E'].transform(thresh_sum)  # Rule 2
m3 = df[~(m1 | m2)].groupby(['A', 'B', 'C'])['E'].transform(thresh_sum, thresh=0.5)  # Rule 4
```

#### 3. `np.select`

Based on the calculated boolean masks `m1`, `m2` and `m3` corresponding to rules `1`, `2` and `4`, fill the values in the column `F`

```
df['F'] = np.select([m1, m2.reindex(m1.index, fill_value=False), m3.reindex(m1.index, fill_value=False)], 
                    ['first three-four col and offset', 'first two col and offset', 'first three-four col and small offset'], 'first or no match')
```

#### Result

```
       A    B    C    D     E                                      F
0   0000  ZZZ  987  QW1   8.0        first three-four col and offset
1   0000  ZZZ  987  QW1  -8.0        first three-four col and offset
2   0000  ZZZ  987  QW1  -8.0                      first or no match
3   1111  AAA  123  AB1   1.0        first three-four col and offset
4   1111  AAA  123  CD1  -1.0        first three-four col and offset
5   2222  BBB  456  EF1  -4.0        first three-four col and offset
6   2222  BBB  456  GH1  -1.0        first three-four col and offset
7   2222  BBB  456  IL1   5.0        first three-four col and offset
8   3333  CCC  789  MN1   2.0               first two col and offset
9   3333  CCC  101  MN1  -2.0               first two col and offset
10  4444  DDD  121  UYT   6.0               first two col and offset
11  4444  DDD  131  FB1  -5.0               first two col and offset
12  4444  DDD  141  UYT  -1.0               first two col and offset
13  5555  EEE  151  CB1   3.0               first two col and offset
14  5555  EEE  161  CR1  -3.0               first two col and offset
15  5555  EEE  161  CR1  -5.0                      first or no match
16  6666  FFF  111  CB1   4.0                      first or no match
17  7777  GGG  222  ZB1  10.5  first three-four col and small offset
18  7777  GGG  222  ZB1 -10.0  first three-four col and small offset
```

Comment: Woah!  Now, let me try to wrap my head around recursive functions in this use case.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a potential start of a solution...  I suspect this logic needs to be a lot more robust to handle your real world dataset.

```
#Read in your dataframe from this question
df = pd.read_clipboard(dtype={'A':'str'})

def f2(x):
    cum = x.cumsum()
    m = (cum == 0)[::-1].cumsum()[::-1].astype(bool)
    x[m]='first two col and offset'
    x[~m]=np.nan
    return x

def f1(x):
    cum = x.cumsum()
    m = (cum == 0)[::-1].cumsum()[::-1].astype(bool)
    x[m]='first three col and offset'
    cl = ((cum.abs() <= .5) & (cum != 0))[::-1].cumsum()[::-1].astype(bool)
    x[cl] = 'first three col and small offset'
    x[~m & ~cl] = np.nan
    return x
    
df['F2'] = df.groupby(['A','B'])['E'].apply(f2)
df['F1'] = df.groupby(['A', 'B', 'C'])['E'].apply(f1)
df['F'] = df['F1'].fillna(df['F2']).fillna('first or no match')
df = df.drop(['F1', 'F2'], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
       A    B    C    D     E                                 F
0   0000  ZZZ  987  QW1   8.0        first three col and offset
1   0000  ZZZ  987  QW1  -8.0        first three col and offset
2   0000  ZZZ  987  QW1  -8.0                 first or no match
3   1111  AAA  123  AB1   1.0        first three col and offset
4   1111  AAA  123  CD1  -1.0        first three col and offset
5   2222  BBB  456  EF1  -4.0        first three col and offset
6   2222  BBB  456  GH1  -1.0        first three col and offset
7   2222  BBB  456  IL1   5.0        first three col and offset
8   3333  CCC  789  MN1   2.0          first two col and offset
9   3333  CCC  101  MN1  -2.0          first two col and offset
10  4444  DDD  121  UYT   6.0          first two col and offset
11  4444  DDD  131  FB1  -5.0          first two col and offset
12  4444  DDD  141  UYT  -1.0          first two col and offset
13  5555  EEE  151  CB1   3.0          first two col and offset
14  5555  EEE  161  CR1  -3.0          first two col and offset
15  5555  EEE  161  CR1  -5.0                 first or no match
16  6666  FFF  111  CB1   4.0                 first or no match
17  7777  GGG  222  ZB1  10.5  first three col and small offset
18  7777  GGG  222  ZB1 -10.0  first three col and small offset
```

**Details:**

- f2, takes a group of 'E' base on the same 'A' and 'B' then computes a
  cumulative sum.
- Then we check to where cumsum equals to 0 to create a boolean series.
- Invert, using [::-1] slicing with a negative one step, that series
  and use cumsum again to flag all the records before the cumsum == 0.
- Revert to original order with [::-1] and cast a boolean.
- Next, use that bolean series' True values to set 'first two col and
  offset', then use the false records to set np.nan.

f1, does same except with extra logic to capture the offset close records.